# Python json - editing a .json file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to add something to a .json file.

This is what saves

```
        "106569102398611456" : {
        "currentlocation" : "Pallet Town",
        "name" : "Anthony",
        "party" : [
            {
                "hp" : "5",
                "level" : "1",
                "pokemonname" : "bulbasaur"
            }
        ],
        "pokedollars" : 0
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make a command to add something else to the "party". Here is an example of what I want.

```
    "106569102398611456" : {
        "currentlocation" : "Pallet Town",
        "name" : "Anthony",
        "party" : [
            {
                "hp" : "5",
                "level" : "1",
                "pokemonname" : "bulbasaur"
            },
            {
                "hp" : "3",
                "level" : "1",
                "pokemonname" : "squirtle"
            }

        ],
        "pokedollars" : 0
    }
}
```

edit:

This is what I've attempted but I have no idea

```
def addPokemon(pokemon):
    pokemonName = convert(pokemon)
    for pokemon in players['party']:
        pokemon.append(pokemonName)
```

convert(pokemon) basically grabs the pokemon i type in and change gives it a level and health to be added to the .json file

Comment: What's wrong with using the `append()` method?

Comment: and what have you tried? can you show us some code? any error message(s)?

Comment: I'm not too sure where to start adding extra stuff into the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a JSON file, write out the object to a temporary file and then replace the target file with the temporary file.  Example:

```
import json
import os
import shutil
import tempfile

def rewriteJsonFile(sourceObj, targetFilePath, **kwargs):
  temp = tempfile.mkstemp()
  tempHandle = os.fdopen(temp[0], 'w')
  tempFilePath = temp[1]
  json.dump(sourceObj, tempHandle, **kwargs)
  tempHandle.close()
  shutil.move(tempFilePath, targetFilePath)
```

This assumes that updates are happening serially.  If updates are potentially happening in parallel, you'd need some kind of locking to ensure only one update is happening at a time.  Although at that point, you're better off using a database like [`sqlite`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) and returning queries in JSON format.